# How to store checkbox value into database?

Tags: database, jsp, checkbox, insert

I have a table which each row have a few checkbox and now i would like to do it if i have click on that checkbox it will update it inside the database. How can i code it using jsp?

Comment: No you're not. Phpmyadmin is an administration tool for mySQL. You're using mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

First define a form in JSP which submits to a servlet.

```
<form action="servleturl" method="post>
```

Then place a checkbox in there with a name and value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" />
```

Then create a servlet which listens on `/servleturl` and gets the parameter in `doPost()` method.

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
```

It'll contain `bar` or `null` depending on checked state. Then you can do your DB thing.

```
fooDAO.save(someID, foo);
```

If that's also a problem already, then you need to learn JDBC and DAO. This is however unrelated to JSP/Servlets. Start with the [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).